# Does Azure API Management support synchronous API calls? If it does then how to implement it?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am a newbie to Azure. I want to implement sync query support using API Management. Can anyone tell me if its some configuration or something

Comment: By default it is async as most modern clients prefer that. But azure management REST apis do provide a sync method extension according to this post https://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2014/04/wamlmaml/  but I have not tried it . If you use  Azure management Libraries available as nuget packages you can do synchronous calls.

Comment: What does "sync query support" mean to you? If you use Azure APIm in front of an API, it is by default synchronous. Making it async requires quite some effort. Azure APIm gets the request, forwards it to the backend, and returns the response, immediately and synchronously. Is that what you are asking?